# How to stop my kitten from playing (clawing/biting) with my hands and fee

Tags: cats, play, claws

Recently I let an orange cat, about 7-8 months old, in the house because its cold outside and one of her canines (I am assuming baby/milk teeths) was missing. But he is so full of energy, he is more interested in playing with my hands and feet instead of eating. I would have been okay with it if it wasn't for the bloody (literal) scratches.

I have tried things like spraying him with water but he really isn't bothered by water (atleast made giving him bath easy). When he scratches my hands/trousers/feet while playing I leave the room and come back after 10-15 mins. But as soon as I enter the room he is at it again. I have tried pretend screaming, crying but nothing works.

Any suggestions for how to stop him from using claws and biting or just simply stopping him from playing with any part of the body.

p.s, when I lift him up and he wants to get down he uses his back paws to kick my hands but doesn't use claws. Claws only come out while playing.

Comment: For the biting and missing tooth consider teething as a cause. So providing alternative things to savely bite into may help the cat to overcome the bad pushing feeling of the new teeth inside the mouth.

Comment: You need to redirect the playfulness - human hands and feet should never be toys, as you have discovered painfully. I guess he’s just bored and full of pent-up energy, so you need to direct him towards toys and other stimulation. The linked Q/A should explain in more depth, what will likely work for your kitten as well.

Comment: Not answered in the lots of suggestions and not something you asked about, but _training_ is also excellent mental stimulation, especially for indoor cats, and tires them out quickly. Plus some commands can be quite useful in different situations, e.g. with grooming and medical care. And it’s great bonding, where typically no claws are involved.